# Rectifier circuit

Tags: rectifier

Questions:

1. How does this circuit work?
2. How can I convert it from 120V to 230V input, but output still remain around 340DC?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please look up _rectifier capacitor voltage doubler_.

Comment: The site provides a tool to draw schematics, which would make yours easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

This is a voltage doubler. It makes use of the fact that the AC input swings to 120v on both sides of zero. This version makes use of a bridge rectifier, but simpler versions exist which use two diodes instead. This simulation shows the operation of that version pretty well:
https://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-voltdouble.html

I like to imagine that it is "stacking" the two sides of the voltage swing against each other. It is also possible to make higher multiplications than two.

Comment: So how to achieve 340 V out if input is 230 V instead (2.)?

Comment: Rectifying 230V (without a doubler) will give you about 320Vdc with no load, since 230V is an RMS measurement, the actual peak-to-peak voltage is about 650. If you need 340V consistently under a variable load your solution may need to be much more complex.